# Replace foil caps with ceramic caps?

Tags: capacitor, battery-charging

I am repairing a battery pack (see below) which has some old foil capacitor (100nF) between a sense Terminal and the negative (together with a NTC thermistor).

[image]

Can I replace the foil cap with a X7R ceramic cap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a leaded X7R capacitor should be fine to replace the film capacitor pictured. There is probably no reason to do so, other than to make it a bit smaller- I would not expect that capacitor to ever fail.

The cap is probably there to reduce noise in the temperature measurement (which would be used for charge termination so noise could truncate the charge cycle).

Comment: +1 on "no reason to do so" - film caps are stable and reliable - considerably moreso than MLCCs (IMHO.)

Comment: Thanks, I am replacing the NiCd in 3 battery packs. Only 1 of them had the cap. 2 of them had only the PTC and the 3rd one had nothing. That's why I am replacing all the components. I doubt the Vishay cap pictured failed.

Answer (score 2):

In your job it's fine to use a ceramic cap but those expensive high quality film caps basically don't fail like Spehro said. In general you can run cheap ceramic where metal film was, but there are some snags preventing replacing every cap everywhere. The tolerances of most high value ceramics is terrible so don't do this in some precision analog circuit. The capacitance  falls with   increasing voltage so things like ramp circuits or high end audio would be a no-no. This capacitance fall that is pronounced on the high values  can mean that you need more microfarads on say a power rail than the film that was replaced .     These caps are much more microphonic so don't use in a sensitive circuit like say a PLL where high vibration is likely.